# Fotorama Responsive Breakpoint

Tags: magento2, rwd, gallery, fotorama

I am having issues with getting fotorama responsive, the breakpoint for a resize is not being actioned. Below is my process of getting this to work:

I changed my themes breakpoint for screen_m via the following method, which worked fine:
`app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/css/source/_variables_extend.less`

```
@screen__m: 991px;
```

The issue I am now faced with is fotorama gallery. I have actioned the following
`app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/etc/view.xml`

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
...
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
        <var name="breakpoints">
            <var name="mobile">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">991px</var>
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </vars>
...
</view>
```

This should then used in the following file:
`Magento_Catalog::/product/view/gallery.phtml`